# "Invalid Operands to Binary" error when trying to calculate square of elements in array

Tags: arrays, c

this code is supposed to read a text file that contains integers, which then finds the squares of these numbers after putting them into an array.
After this its supposed to print the results onto a new text file "result.txt", but I keep getting the error "invalid operands to binary*(have 'int*' and 'int*')" on this line: square[x] = square[x] * square[x];

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int square[100][2];
    int x;
    int i;

    FILE* input=fopen("in.csv","r");
    FILE * f=fopen("result.txt","wb");
    system("cls");

    for(x=0;x<100;x++)
    {
        fscanf(input,"%d",&square[x][0]);
    }

    fclose(input);

    for(x=0;x<100;x++)
    {
        square[x] = square[x] * square[x]; //this line produces the error
    }

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        fprintf(f,"%d -> %d || ",square[i][0],square[i][1]);
    }

    fclose(f);
    getchar();
}
```

I am using Eclipse IDE and MinGW-w64
I have tried finding solutions online but am stuck, any help or replies would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`square[x]` yields an array with two elements. You should reference the `[0]` and `[1]` elements like you do in the rest of your code.

```
square[x][1] = square[x][0] * square[x][0];
```